# Remove a part of string from one character to another

Tags: python, python-2.7

For the following strings in a string:

```
User Input(id=2345) : Hello
User Input(id=9423924) : Hi!
User Input(id=233123) : How's it going
```

I want to remove the part in the brackets. 
to look something like:

```
User Input: Hello
User Input: Hi!
User Input: How's it going
```

I have tried the follow code:

```
import re
file = file1.read()
for line in file
   print(re.sub(r'\((.*?)\line)\+', '', line))
```

it gives me an error- any suggestions would be really helpful!
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions:

```
>>> s = 'User Input(id=2345) : Hello'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\(.+?\)', '', s)
'User Input : Hello'
```

This will not work super robustly for nested brackets, but for the input at hand, it should do just fine.